# numbers that correspond to a row and column on a matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

[image][image]

I have created this matrix in matplotlib, some of the coordinates are `[(1,109),(2,109),(2,130),(2,131),(2,132)]` and so on. I also have a list of letter ['A', 'B' 'H', 'A', 'H']
each letter corresponds to a row and a column of the matrix.
How can find out, how big each each square of the matrix is?
later on I want to produce a colour part, which is related to the matrix, which is dependent on the list of letters.
So the first A is related to the point on the matrix (1,109) so the color part lets say red for A is lined up with that row and column and is as wide as the square situated there.
The second B is related to (2,109) with the color blue, it is lined up with that row and column and is as wide as the square situated there

The color on this is what I am getting at, each color section applies to a particular section of points, so when its a large portion of blue there are a large portion of Bs that are next to each other

Comment: Your question is difficult to parse.  Are all the points that occur within a given color section actually row/column pairs from your matrix?  Am I right in thinking that you expect to see a square for each color?

Comment: I have edited my question hopefully it is easier to understand

Comment: Could you edit it to say specifically how the coordinates and letters come together to create squares in your matrix?  Are the squares actually in your matrix?  Or are they squares on the graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but I'll take a stab at it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.array([(1,1),(2,9),(2,3),(2,1),(2,2)])
letters = ['A', 'B', 'H', 'A', 'H']
colormap = {'A':(1,0,0),'B':(0,0,1),'H':(0,1,0)}

N = data.max() + 5
# color the background white (1 is white)
arr = np.ones((N,N,3))

for (x,y), letter in zip(data,letters):
    # color the point at (x,y) black
    arr[x,y] = (0,0,0)
    # color the x=0 band
    arr[0,y] =  colormap[letter]
    # color the y=N-1 band
    arr[x,N-1] =  colormap[letter]    

arr = arr.swapaxes(0,1)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

ax.imshow(arr, interpolation='nearest')
ax.invert_yaxis()
# ax.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]